# Strange UITableView scroll indicator inset when the table goes underneath the tabbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a problem with a UITableView where the scroll indicator starts off too low, there is a space between the top position of the scroll indicator and the actual top of the tableview, as if there is an inset or offset set. This happens when I make the tableview go underneath the tabbar (superview bottom = 0), it does not happen if the tableview stops right above the tabbar (bottom layout guide = 0). I've marked the tableview size in the screenshots below.

[image: above the tabbar]
[image: below the tabbar]

I've added some print statements to see what is going on, but they all return zero for all values.

```swift
print(tableView.contentOffset)
print(tableView.contentInset)
print(tableView.adjustedContentInset)
print(tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets)
```

How can I remove this weird spacing?

Comment: guess this is related to automatic scroll view insets. Try to disable in storyboard. (select VC -> attributes -> Layout -> Uncheck Adjust ScrollView Insets)

Comment: There is the "content inset adjustment behavior" toggle which can be set to "never", but sadly that doesn't change anything. Not sure what toggle you mean 

Comment: I meant [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgpel.png)

Comment: Ah! Sadly no difference either though :(

Comment: This is also happening for me and I don't think it's related to the tab bar (because I don't have one) but is related to extending the table to the bottom of the superview instead of the safe area. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm able to make it go away by setting `isTranslucent` to `true` on the navigation bar, but obviously that's no good if you want an opaque bar.

Comment: @arlomedia is right, I noticed this problem with all tableViews constraint to superview bottom. I've set the top scroll indicator inset = -1 to remedy this.